# Convert a specific google sheets tab into a pdf

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

For a project I am currently working on I'm trying to find a way that lets me turn a specific google sheets tab into a pdf using javascript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your own id in this script

```
function savePDF(){

  const docID = '______id of the spreadsheet________';
  const feuilleID = '___id of the sheet______';
  const dossier = DriveApp.getFolderById('______id of the folder_______');
  const fichier = 'name of the file.pdf'

  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + docID + '/export?';
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
    '&size=A4' + 
    '&portrait=true' +
    '&fitw=false' +
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' +
    '&fzr=false' +
    '&gid=' + feuilleID;
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var reponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions, params).getBlob(); 
  dossier.createFile(reponse.setName(fichier));
}
```